# wifi key does not work

Tags: shortcut-keys, hp, acpi

After the installation of Ubuntu 17.10 some keys do not work correctly.

My PC: HP ENVY 15 J108LA

My problem is the wireless (f12) and mute or sound off (f6) keys. In the case of the wifi key, it does not activate or deactivate the wifi (it does not perform any action).

With the mute key or sound off, it does not turn on the red LED of the same key, as for example the case lock key does.

The other keys work correctly (uppercase block, f1, f2, f3, f4 ...), even the keyboard illumination key works, but I have no idea why the previous keys do not work as they should.

Output of `lsmod | cut -d ' ' -f 1`:

```
rfcomm
ccm
cmac
bbswitch
bnep
snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_hda_codec_idt
snd_hda_codec_generic
cmdlinepart
intel_spi_platform
intel_spi
spi_nor
mtd
uvcvideo
videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_memops
videobuf2_v4l2
intel_rapl
videobuf2_core
wmi_bmof
hp_wmi
sparse_keymap
videodev
x86_pkg_temp_thermal
media
intel_powerclamp
coretemp
snd_hda_intel
kvm_intel
snd_hda_codec
kvm
snd_hda_core
arc4
irqbypass
wl
snd_hwdep
snd_pcm
crct10dif_pclmul
crc32_pclmul
btusb
btrtl
btbcm
btintel
iwlmvm
mac80211
iwlwifi
cfg80211
rtsx_pci_ms
memstick
ghash_clmulni_intel
snd_seq_midi
bluetooth
snd_seq_midi_event
pcbc
shpchp
snd_rawmidi
aesni_intel
snd_seq
snd_seq_device
snd_timer
snd
soundcore
ecdh_generic
aes_x86_64
mei_me
ie31200_edac
mei
lpc_ich
crypto_simd
glue_helper
joydev
input_leds
cryptd
intel_cstate
intel_rapl_perf
serio_raw
nvidia_uvm
soc_button_array
mac_hid
hp_accel
lis3lv02d
input_polldev
hp_wireless
intel_smartconnect
wmi
parport_pc
ppdev
lp
parport
ip_tables
x_tables
autofs4
hid_generic
usbhid
hid
nvidia_drm
nvidia_modeset
i915
rtsx_pci_sdmmc
nvidia
i2c_algo_bit
drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea
sysfillrect
sysimgblt
fb_sys_fops
psmouse
ahci
r8169
drm
libahci
rtsx_pci
mii
video
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya incluí la salida del comando.

Comment: Alright. I don't speak Spanish but I know enough Latin to understand that sentence. In general, please restrict your communication on Ask Ubuntu to English as it is the only formally accepted language here. Thanks.